# why Button is hidden inside Textarea , after moving the button inside textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to move a button from outside to inside of textarea using javascript

```
messageSubject.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend',_sendbtn);
```

it moves the send button inside the textarea but is not visible to ui now.

HTML

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <textarea name="subject" required="Required" id="messageSubject" maxlength="501" validatewhiletyping="true" placeholder="Please enter the subject" aria-labelledby="intro-message-subject">
        <button class="dx-submit dx-btn dx-btn-primary " id="_sendbtn" aria-label="Send your message">Send</button>
        </textarea>
        <span class="sr-only"></span>
        <div role="region" id="messagesubjectValidation" aria-live="assertive"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

css

```
  #messageSubject{
    margin-bottom:5px;
    box-shadow:none;
    }
    .dx-btn-primary{
    background:blue;
    border:1px solid;
    color:white;
    padding:4px 10px;
    text-align:center;
    }
.dx-btn{
font-size:16px;
font-weight:inherit;
display:inline-block;
}

.dx-widget .cx-btn{
display:inline-block;
margin-bottom:0;
line-height:1.666em;
white-space:nowrap;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

I have tried using position:absolute for button and position:relative for textarea but didn't worked.

Comment: Because `textarea` _can not_ contain child _elements_, but only text …?

Comment: But I have seen  textarea with button . I had also tried positioning using right and top but doesn't work.

Comment: Just because you saw the _visual result_ you want somewhere, does not mean it was based on that kind of – impossible – structure. Put the textarea and the button into a container element (button _outside_ of the textarea tags), then you can position the button absolute to the relative container.

Comment: @CBore Understood,thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty simple actually-you can't.
The button you've seen was probably a button in a div tag with contenteditable set to true (or the button was outside of the textarea).
[More about contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable)